# Seminar in Algebraic Topology/Homological Algebra

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm currently studying for my Homological Algebra exam and I have to give a seminar. Since, how it's very well known, homological algebra is very related to algebraic topology and since I wuold learn more about algebraic topolgy, I want give my seminar about some topic regarding algebraic topology. At the moment my knowledge about algebraic topology is the the following: fundamental group, higher homotopy groups, singular homology and cohomology. For what concerns my homological algebra course, the topics are the standard ones, i.e. abelian categories, chain complexes, derived functors, $\mathsf{Tor}$ and $\mathsf{Ext}$ and spectral sequences. Can you suggest me some good topic for my seminar? Maybe also some papers that I can study with my current skills?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like Poincare duality or Alexander duality including a proof of the Jordan curve theorem. If that is too basic, another possibility would be about bordism and signature.